# COMException error on Excel.Worksheet.Copy when other workbook has a chart selected

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

We have an application that is an Excel Addin built using VSTO.  We use Excel as a reporting tool.  When I open a report (workbook) and select a chart, then open another workbook, I get a COMException error.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC    at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.Copy(Object Before, Object After)
```

This ONLY happens when I have a chart selected.  Here's the code that is causing an issue.  (The DocumentView is an Excel Workbook.)

```
 private void CopyInitialSheets()
    {
        try
        {
            int sheetCount;
            Excel.Worksheet initialSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)StingerGlobal.AppData.ExcelApp.ActiveSheet;
            initialSheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;  
            List<string> sheetNames = new List<string>(this.DocumentView.Sheets.Count);

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in this.DocumentView.Sheets)
            {

                sheetNames.Add(sheet.Name);
            }

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in _sheetReports.Keys)
            {
                Excel.Worksheet veryHiddenSheet = null;
                sheetCount = this.DocumentView.Sheets.Count;
                sheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;  
                sheet.Copy(Type.Missing, this.DocumentView.Sheets[sheetCount]);
                //Copy all the images, Charts, etc.  These don't copy over with the sheet.
                foreach (Excel.Shape o in sheet.Shapes)
                {
                    switch (o.Type)
                    {
                        case Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoPicture:
                            o.CopyPicture();
                            break;
                        case Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoChart:
                        case Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoDiagram:
                        case Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoCanvas:
                            o.Copy();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                //Find the sheet I just added because the after param to the Copy function is not respected.
                foreach (Excel.Worksheet newSheet in this.DocumentView.Sheets)
                {
                    if (sheetNames.Contains(newSheet.Name))
                        continue;  //Don't want this as it is an original sheet.
                    if (newSheet.Name.Contains("--VH--"))
                        continue;  //Don't want this as it is one of my copies.
                    //If code gets here, then I found the one I want
                    veryHiddenSheet = newSheet;
                }

                veryHiddenSheet.Name = MakeHiddenSheetName(sheet.Name, "--VH--");  //Do not localize.
                veryHiddenSheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVeryHidden;
            }

            //Make sure the first initial sheet is still active after we are done.
            ((Excel._Worksheet)initialSheet).Activate();
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
```

This only has a problem on the second workbook, and works fine on the first.  My best guess is that Excel is somehow mixing up the workbooks and causing some memory error.  I have tried the following:
- Clearing the clipboard
- Deselecting the chart of the active sheet (this is in the first workbook)
- Ignoring the Exception (this stopped the copy process and the sheet later couldn't be found when needed)
- Activating the open sheet of the new workbook

None of these have worked.  So far the only solution is don't select a chart. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I had this issue, I'd select a cell at the beginning of the procedure.

In VBA: application.GoTo Activeworkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")